# How to find the running time of a service or program in Windows

Tags: windows, operating-system, exe

I am trying to create a tracking application to track the amount of time I spend on Gaming or web activities. One of the task is to get the time an application or process has been run in Windows system. This can be stored in some database and will later be accessed by my Java program Need help obtaining this information programmatically.

Comment: I think your best bet is to have a service which queries periodically the running process list, let's say very 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use powershell to find out these :

```
New-TimeSpan -Start (get-process "outlook").StartTime
```